# Problems instaling Ubuntu 13.10 on a MacBook Pro 11.2

Tags: system-installation, 13.10, macbook

I am new to Ubuntu, but I decided to install it on my newly gained MacBook Pro 11.2.

I have four issues:

1. In live mode, the screen crushed, I can hardly see clearly unless I plug in an external LCD.
2. In installation, I can't see the *Install alongside OS X* option.
3. After installation, the screen is fixed, but I can't get the wifi to work, because there is internal error (`Broken count>0`) that stops me from using `sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source` And any command like `sudo apt-get install` won't work. `DKMS` is also missing.
4. When I reboot, trying to boot Mac, OS X never shows up. For 32-bit it doesn't allow me to boot, for 64-bit the screen keeps showing nothing for a long time before I reboot.

Basically I followed [these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro11-1/Saucy).

I didn't use reFind or reFit. I burned the iso on a USB drive and partitioned free space for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

1. Run the live cd with `quiet nomodeset` option. This should allow you to see what you are doing.
2. Did you install alongside OSX or something else? It's not clear what exactly you have done.

What bootloader do you intend to use if not refind? Will you be using grub to manage your startup or something else?